# Issue with 2nd y axis using sec.axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot two sets of data: ch4 (scale of data is ~2e-06) and altitude (scale of data is ~10). I am using the `sec.axis` command in `ggplot2`. I can't get it to correctly scale both data sets. If I don't use limits within `scale_y_continuous` the ch4 data appear as a flat line because the left hand axis is scaled to altitude. If I include limits within `scale_y_continuou`s my ch4 data plots ok, but altitude doesn't show up at all (even though the righthand axis scale is on the appropriate scale) Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Example data:

```
timestamp  ch4        alt

47232.42 1.923e-06  0.44

47232.57 1.908e-06  1.38

47232.77 1.931e-06  5.93

47233.03 1.946e-06  12.01

47233.20 1.904e-06  6.43

47233.43 1.913e-06  0.42
```

Example code where ch4 is a flat line:

```
basicplot <- ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=timestamp)) +

  geom_line(aes(y=ch4), color="red") +

  geom_line(aes(y=alt), color="blue") +

  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 20/0.000002, name="altitude"))

print(basicplot)
```

Example code where altitude doesn't appear (even though right-hand scale seems ok):

```
basicplot <- ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=timestamp)) +

  geom_line(aes(y=alt), color="blue") +

  geom_line(aes(y=ch4), color="red") +

  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 20/0.000002, name="altitude"), limits = c(0, 0.000005))

print(basicplot)
```

Comment: You should apply the same transformation to `ch4` as you do to the secondary axis it relates to, e.g. `y=ch4 * 20 / 0.000002`. Best practice would probably be to define that scaling coefficient outside the plot, and refer to that for both, to help keep them aligned if you ever want to change.

Comment: I think I actually have to do the reverse of the scalar I use in the sec.axis in the code. So plotting that data needs to have this code: geom_line(aes(y=alt * 0.000002/20), color="blue"). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
scale_coeff <- 20/0.000002

ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=timestamp)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=alt / scale_coeff), color="blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y=ch4), color="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "ch4", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * scale_coeff, name="altitude"))  +
  theme(axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "blue"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue"))
```

[image]

```
mydata<- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "timestamp  ch4        alt
47232.42 1.923e-06  0.44
47232.57 1.908e-06  1.38
47232.77 1.931e-06  5.93
47233.03 1.946e-06  12.01
47233.20 1.904e-06  6.43 
47233.43 1.913e-06  0.42")
```